# Add class to top level menu item if it has multiple child levels

Tags: menus, walker, sub-menu

I have a WP nav menu, and I need to add a class to any top-level `<li>` if that item has more than one level of child items (meaning, its child submenu has a submenu too). Like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Parent
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>Sublink1</li>
            <li>Sublink2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Parent</li>
    <li class="ADD-CLASS-HERE">Parent <!-- add class to this item -->
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>Sublink1</li>
            <li>Sublink2</li>
            <li>Sublink3
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li>Sublink1</li>
                    <li>Sublink2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Parent</li>
    <li>Parent</li>
    <li>Parent
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>Sublink1</li>
            <li>Sublink2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm assuming I need to use a Walker to achieve this. (I don't want to manually add the class in the WP Menu settings.) I've tried working with some example walkers I found, but I haven't been able to get the class added to the level 0 ancestor item. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure, but maybe something like this will work? Add to the functions.php.
See explanation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#How_to_add_a_parent_class_for_menu_item).

```
//This function is responsible for adding "my-parent-item" class to parent menu item's
function add_menu_parent_class( $items ) {
$parents = array();
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    //Check if the item is a parent item
    if ( $item->menu_item_parent && $item->menu_item_parent > 0 ) {
        $parents[] = $item->menu_item_parent;
    }
}

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    if ( in_array( $item->ID, $parents ) ) {
        //Add "menu-parent-item" class to parents
        $item->classes[] = 'my-parent-item';
    }
}

return $items;
}

//add_menu_parent_class to menu
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'add_menu_parent_class' );
```

So if you  can use Jquery you can do it like this:

```
$('ul li.menu-parent-item:has(ul ul)').addClass('your class');
```

Comment: Thank you. This adds a class to all parents that have children, so I need to figure out a way to modify this so that it only adds the "my-parent-item" class to top level (level zero?) parent items and ONLY if that top level item has multiple child levels, not just one level. That's the part I'm struggling with. Tricky!

Comment: I suppose applying the class to top level only isn't necessary, but I do need to only apply it to items that have more than 1 level of children.

Comment: If you can use Jquery it is rather simple see the edit...

Comment: I figured I'd resort to jquery if I couldn't figure it out with a walker, so thank you for the additional edit. Since it's an important style, I was hoping to achieve it with php in case people have JS turned off. But maybe JS is the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: I'm marking this correct for the jQuery part of your answer, which I ended up using. I was not able to get a php/walker solution to work.

Comment: @DejoDekic this code add class all parents, how to add class only parent `li`. js dont help. the point is active page not in menu, its post...